# output a variable during vagrant provision with chef solo

Tags: bash, debugging, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Hi I simply want to see an output of an variable that is set in a chef bash block. Based on whether Django is already installed or not. My recipe looks like this.

```
bash 'install django and gunicorn' do
  code <<-EOH
  source /djenv/bin/activate
  if [ pip3 list | grep django ]
    then
      answer = 'Django already installed'
    else
      pip3 install gunicorn
      pip3 install django
      answer = 'Installed django and gunicorn'
  fi
  export answer
  deactivate
 EOH
 Chef::Log.info($answer)
end

#log 'message' do
# message = $answer
# level :info
#end
```

All I see during vagrant provision is

> bash[install django] ran successfully

but i want to see the output of my variable telling what really happend.
The commented log block did not work also. Chef::Log.info(bla) is also not doing anything.

**Update:**

Alright no trying the same with attributes.
I created an default.rb file with a normal['django']['status'] attribute with an initial 'notset' value.
And changed my recipe to this.

```
bash 'install django and gunicorn' do
 code <<-EOH
 source /djenv/bin/activate
 if [ pip3 list | grep django ]
  then
   #{node.normal['django']['status']} = 'Django already installed'
  else
    pip3 install gunicorn
    pip3 install django
   #{node.normal['django']['status']} = 'Installed Django and Gunicorn'
 fi
 deactivate
 EOH
 notifies :write, 'log[message]', :immediate
 end

log 'message' do
  message node['django']['status']
  level :info
  action :nothing
end
```

But all I get is a

> INFO: notset

so inside of the bash block there is no new assignment to the variable .....
I know that itś most probably not the way to do something like this .... but I am learning chef and experimenting to learn it ... something like that.

Comment: thanks for downvoting ... and giving so many good hints .... a big thumb up for all those proffesionals out there

Comment: be mature and do not pay attention to fake internet points. Regarding your question: as I said earlier I highly doubt you can set a ruby variable in a bash block. All examples in the docs are for string interpolation. Try to explain reasoning behind your intention with this